# Cmake error when installing

Tags: apt, software-installation, virtualbox, compiling, cmake

I installed Ubuntu in VirtualBox for trying a software made only for Linux.

I'm getting this error when trying to install the software. Not sure if it's an error in the steps of the installation or a result of my lack of knowledge in Linux.

> Cmake error at CmakeLists.txt
>
> The Cmake_C Compiler.
>
> Path_to_emsdk/upstream/emscripten/emcc
>
> is not a full path and was not found in path
>
> Tell Cmake where to find the compiler by setting either the enviroment
> variable "CC" or the Cmake cache entry CMAKE_C_COMPILER to the full
> path to the compiler, or to the compiler name if it is in the PATH.

I already tried things like

> sudo apt-get update
>
> sudo apt-get install -y build-essential
>
> sudo apt-get install g++

but they didnt work. Any idea what could it be?

Comment: `CMake` is to create the build system in order to create (compile) a piece of software.  Another way of saying this is that `CMake` is used to build something that is used to build your software.  Based on the error you're seeing, it looks like the file that is input into `CMake` (usually called `CMakeLists.txt`) has an error.   For example, it cannot find the C compiler.  You should ask the developer of the program you're trying to install for help and to see what prerequisites you need.  You should not have to guess about `build-essential`, etc.; the developer should tell you somehow.

Comment: @ray I found the error, it turned out to be the file Cmake_cache had an error, it had the path to the compiler wrong.

Comment: Oh, that's good.  A "properly" written `CMakeLists.txt` should be able to find the compiler "automatically" with minimal tweaking.  That is why I suggested you revert back to the developer to ask.  You may also end up helping him/her improve the software. Anyway, good that you found the cause!

Comment: @ray I'm actually sending reports to the developer, but since the last one was 4 months ago, I suspect it could take days or weeks for them to answer.